# Is IndexedDb dependent on cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, indexeddb, offlineapps

I am working on a prototype where we need to support offline data modification of web application, the application is expected to sync back the data when an internet connection is restored. I have taken a look at various HTML5 in-browser storage option and indexeddb looked like the one I wanted. But I am not sure if the data will be persisted between browser close. Is that possible? One more question if I delete the cookie of the browser, will data in indexedDb will be wiped out? My initial tests shows data gets deleted on cookie clear of browser.

If indexeddb is not a viable option, are there any other alternatives to it which can persist data when internet connection is not available?

Answer (score 2):

As per specification database created with indexedDB should be persistent acrross navigation and browser session.

But current implementation is like `persistent cookies`. So removal of cookies might remove your database too.

As per google chrome indexedDB is a type of temporary storage.

**Chrome:** https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage

For microsoft & firefox it is persitent :

**Microsoft:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/hh563494.aspx

**Firefox:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB

Check supported browsers before use.

http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb

Answer (score 1):

It isn't dependent on a cookie, though if you need to know who the user is (likely) you'll probably end up using a cookie of some variety...

As for offline sychronization... I thought about this a lot previously and created a project... The documentation for it is detailed and explains why and how... It may help, or at least give you things to think about. It has very recently been updated to support IndexedDB!

http://forbesmyester.github.io/SyncIt/index.html

In this space there is also RemoteStorage ( they were/are looking at using SyncIt + other bits in the project going forward ), Hood.ie and the commercial FireBase in this field.

Comment: I have actually tried across browsers. Not sure when I have cleared cookie the data in indexedb cleaned up. Not sure if I am testing right

Comment: OK, weird... it definitely persists across sessions, why does the cookie bother you? Particularly if you are synchronising as the data will come down again if the user does delete it?

Comment: The application that I am trying to build is an inspection type application. Therefore user will be offline with the application for a few days. And when they come back on then they can sync the data back. However in between if they clear their browser cookie all the inspection data will be lost.

Comment: With above scenario you described, I would suggest you to go with native application instead web app.

Comment: @SD. Offline HTML/JS/CSS is well supported and documented. If a company/person is skilled with those tools and not with __both__ Java and ObjectiveC/Swift that's a big call... Are there native libraries and/or API's which make developing such an application significantly easier?

Comment: @qamar The odds are you'll use cookies to keep the user logged in (for sync) and besides, I'm not sure it's at all reasonable to expect any app to exist when a user wilfully destroys some data that the application has created.

Comment: @Forbesmyester just to update you folks I have decided to go with couchdb at backend and pouchdb for temporal persistence of data. pouchdb has sync infra built in for pouchdb out of the box. Thanks for your opinion folks.